# Why Uri used in MediaPlayer static method create() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-mediaplayer, illegalargumentexception

The problem is that when we use a `uri` to get the instance of `Mediaplayer` class using `Mediaplayer.create(Context, uri)` it throws `exception` as of below :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

The above exception occurs when we have path of music files is in Url Encoded form (`i.e,path : storage/sdcard/song%20music%20file.mp3`) the path is of `phone storage` and `not the url` of song on internet.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
//the below line creates the problem.
mediaplayer = Mediaplayer.create(context, uri);
```

while in other cases of path of the files it works like charm why this problem occurs and if there is any way of resolving this problem how can we do this ? Any suggestion,help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like below to solve the issue :

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Uri.encode(path));
//then use myUri like
mediaplayer = Mediaplayer.create(context, myUri);
```